# Why is the oxidation of sulfur dioxide not termed as heat of formation of sulfur trioxide?

Tags: thermodynamics

According to me, the following reaction's heat should be termed as heat of formation of sulfur trioxide:

$$\ce{SO2 + 1/2 O2 -> SO3}$$

However, in my textbook, they have that given it is not the formation reaction. Why is it so? And which is the formation reaction then?

Comment: There are quite a few _different_ reactions that end up in SO3. Which of them should be called _formation_?

Comment: Thanks for editing my question. After reading the edited question, I have come up with an answer(not sure if I am correct or not). The heat of formation of sulfur trioxide, instead of being the heat of reaction of the above reaction, is the sum of the heat of reaction of a two-step reaction(because the formation of sulfur trioxide is a two-step reaction).

Comment: @Gordon I don't think the number of steps is relevant. In fact, as Karl has mentioned in their answer below, it is entirely irrelevant whether it is possible to even produce the compound in that single reaction.

Comment: @GaurangTandon Yes and no. If the actual synthesis of the product takes multiple steps then you can still calculate the heat of formation by adding up the details at each step. Yes the umber of steps doesn't matter, but *real* reactions of multiple steps can still get you to the answer.

Answer (score 5):

*Heat of formation* is the enthalpy difference to *the elements* in standard state as defined by IUPAC, which is in most cases their most thermodynamically stable form at STP.

It is completely *irrelevant* if the respective chemical equation makes any sense, i.e. it would work out in a laboratory. However high the number of intermediate steps to reach the desired product is, energy is always conserved.

Comment: Always seems to be an exception. Black phosphorus is more thermodynamically stable  than white  phosphorus which was chosen as the standard state.

Comment: @MaxW Yes, i think white phosphorus is the only modification at STP which can be readily produced and has a well defined crystal structure and density. The polymeric forms (black, red, violett) are notorious for containing a huge amount of packing defects.

Answer (score 5):

The heat of a reaction $\ce{A + B + ... -> X}$ is called the standard heat of formation of the product subject to a number of strict restrictions. These restrictions are:

1. Each of the reactants must be in their *thermodynamically most stable* state at the room temperature. For example, if you take bromine as a reactant, it must be in liquid state. If you take carbon, it must be graphite (s), etc. Also, polyatomic molecules must be written in complete molecules and not atoms (hence, $\ce{Br2}$ and not $\ce{Br}$)
2. Each of the reactants must themselves be elements and not compounds. For example, $\ce{C (s, graphite) + O2 (g) -> CO2 (g)}$ is correct, but $\ce{CO (g) + 1/2 O2 (g) -> CO2 (g)}$ is incorrect as $\ce{CO}$ is *not* an element.
3. There should be only *one* product and that too the one we're concerned about.
4. There should only be *one* mole of the product. Hence, $\ce{S (s) + 3/2 O2 (g) -> SO3 (g)}$ is correct, but $\ce{2S (s) + 3 O2 (g) -> 2 SO3 (g)}$ is incorrect (actually, the latter's heat of reaction is just double of the standard enthalpy of formation).

You can read more about the standard enthalpy of formation on [the Wikipedia page.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_enthalpy_of_formation#)

Can you now tell by which rule your given reaction fails to be a standard formation reaction?

---

Also, here's a fun little exercise: can you tell which of the following reactions are standard formation reactions?

1. $\ce{PCl5}$

   - $\ce{P (white, s)  + 5/2 Cl2 (g) -> PCl5 (s)}$
   - $\ce{P (black, s)  + 5/2 Cl2 (g) -> PCl5 (s)}$
   - $\ce{P (white, s)  + 5 Cl (g) -> PCl5 (s)}$
2. $\ce{KCl}$

   - $\ce{K (s) + 1/2 Cl2 (g) -> KCl (s)}$
   - $\ce{K (g) + 1/2 Cl2 (g) -> KCl (g)}$ (a homogenous mixture!)
   - $\ce{2K (s) + Cl2 (g) -> 2KCl (s)}$
3. $\ce{O2}$

   - $\ce{KClO3 (s) ->[\Delta] KClO (s) + O2 (g)}$
   - $\ce{2Na2O (s) ->[\Delta] 4Na (s) + O2 (g)}$
   - $\ce{H2O (g) + CO2 (g) -> 1/6 C6H12O6 (l) + O2 (g)}$